# How to find the second focus of an ellipse in a cartesian coordinate system

Tags: applications, simulation, elliptic-equations

For a university project, I'm creating a to scale (using real values of distance, mass etc) simulation of the solar system using Python with the aim of demonstrating Kepler's Laws.

Currently, I have a physics engine made where I calculate a planets position using Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation which looks something like the image [linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyHaX.png).

I've only included the first 5 planets for clarity.

The next step im trying to implement is displaying the second focus of the elliptical orbits. I'm aware this will be very close to the sun for most planets although I'd still like to be able to implement it and eventually draw the ellipse. I have all relevant information available for constructing the ellipse, mainly the semi-major axis and eccentricity and positions of the objects.

My question is, knowing the position of the sun, a planet and the relevant information, how can i calculate the second focus of the ellipse. It's not something that I'd like to hardcode either as the planets orbits are affected by one another meaning that the orientation of the ellipse changes over time.

Initially, I tried creating two conceptual circles, one on the planet and one at the sun with radiuses equal to the distance to the second focus and then finding the intercept point of the two circles however this didn't work as intended. The sun is positioned at rougly (0, 0) although the first focus is actually the center of mass of the system so isn't a fixed position and is constantly moving, so ideally a solution would be a general solution that works with any two points (x1, y1), (x2, y2).

Answer (score 1):

Connect the point $A$ of maximal distance Earth-Sun to the point $B$ of minimal distance Earth-Sun. This is one of the axes of the ellipse and should pass through the Sun. The center of the ellipse is the midpoint $O$ of the segment between the point $A, B$ and the two focuses are symmetric with respect to this midpoint (so the other focus $F$ is the intersection of the line $SO$, where $S$ is the point where the Sun is, and the circle of center $O$ and passing through $S$)

Comment: That makes sense and I have considered it as more hard-coded approach, however the point of maximal distance for the Earth-Sun system is constantly moving so this isn't entirely practical.

Comment: But you can picture the orbit of the Earth as an ellipse rotating with center of rotation the Sun (I don't know how precise this approximation is), so you can "fix" this ellipse and find the other focus as in the answer. Then, as the Earth rotates around the Sun, the other focus rotate around the Sun as well

Comment: The movement of the center of mass of the system, and the ellipse that governs the orbit, is not easily calculated. I linked it above but heres a graphical representation of how the barycenter (one of the focus) moves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#/media/File:Solar_system_barycenter.svg

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the semimajor axis and $\epsilon$ be the eccentricity of the orbit. Then each focus is $a\epsilon$ from the center of the ellipse.

Comment: I understand this, how do I find its orientation relative to the system though?

Comment: do you know the rotation of the semimajor axis?

Comment: also, i'm a bit confused about when you say "the first focus is the center of mass of the system so isn't a fixed position and is constantly moving," because in the absence of external forces, the COM remains fixed.

Comment: The rotation of the semi-major axis is chaning because of the change in center of mass. From what I understand this is because of the effect the other planets have on each others orbits. There's a good visual representation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#/media/File:Solar_system_barycenter.svg